# DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) not working

Tags: mysql

I am running a MySQL query to get back to the results in the last 14 days. When I run the following query it keeps returning empty. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here

Below is the query I am running

```
SELECT * FROM checkout_page WHERE checkout_date =  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you want everything from 14 days ago at midnight onward, or exactly 14 days ago from the present time onward?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a record which checkout_date is **exactly 14 days** before current time which is very unlikely to happen thus you will get empty result most of the time. What you want is records happens after that, thus instead of `=`, change to `>=`

`SELECT * FROM checkout_page WHERE checkout_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);`

Comment: Hi, 

 Yes you are right. What I did to get exactly 14 days was using this following query

Comment: SELECT * FROM checkout_page WHERE DATE(checkout_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY  ;

Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: @Jon if you find support to your question from this answer. Why you put separate answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. However, I found out this following query worked

```
 SELECT * FROM checkout_page WHERE DATE(checkout_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY  ;
```